# Change Title column of SharePoint list

Tags: list

I want to rename the title column to ItemTitle in sharepoint list. How can i achieve this? I tried the below code:

```
SPList splist = spWeb.Lists["ListName"];
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
splist.Fields["Title"].Title = "Item Title";
splist.Fields["Title"].Update();
splist.Update();
spWeb.Update();
spWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```

This code i am performing on `WebProvisioned` event. I want that whenvever the new site is created the title column of the particular list should be renamed to "Item Title".

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var field = splist.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.Title];
field.Title = "Item Title";
field.Update();

field = splist.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.LinkTitle];
field.Title = "Item Title";
field.Update();

field = splist.Fields[SPBuiltInFieldId.LinkTitleNoMenu];
field.Title = "Item Title";
field.Update();
```

The `Title` column has other Calculated columns which are used in Views `LinkTitle` and `LinkTitleNoMenu`, you need to update these as well.

Comment: Its not working.

Comment: Actually i have two title column with same display name as "Title". Does the issue is due to this or anything else?

Comment: Can you check the Internal Name of the columns.. Go to List Settings and click the column, In the URL you will have the Internal Name of the field/column

Comment: One is Title1 and one is Title

Comment: I can change the name of other column but not the Title